# Center content of the col-md-# component

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center three images within the row class that I have set to a div.
I am using bootstrap but i do not find a way to center the contents of each col-md-# class component. How can I center the contents? 
My code is as follows:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
       <div class="container">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/1.png"> <br />
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                   <img src="img/2.png"> <br />
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="img/3.png"> <br />
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.
I have tried many ways even the inline style formatting but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the text-center class on your columns.  Note that it will only center inline elements so wether it will actually work for you depends on what content you have in your columns.

It should work for basic images.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css img

```
.col-md-4 img {
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

it will work

[demo here](http://www.bootply.com/dx6poQB7D9)